# Recargar mi tabla AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de hacer que una tabla se actualice automáticamente, mediante una llamada de`AJAX`, por ejemplo cuando cambio el rango de fechas estas se mandan a un modelo que ejecuta una función y toma los parámetros y realiza la consulta.

El problema aquí es que no me actualiza mi taba mi `JSON`, si trae los datos pero no me pinta la tabla, utilizo `bootstrap-tables`.

Este es como tengo el código hasta ahora,

```
function actualizarTabla(datoFechaIni, datoFechaFin) {
  obtenerTablaAjax('ejemplo', '<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/modulos/diegov/ejemplo/datos', {
    fechaIni: datoFechaIni,
    fechaFin: datoFechaFin
  }, '<?= base_url("assets/img/elems/loader.gif"); ?>');
}

function cargaInicial() {

  $("#e-fechaInicio").change(function() {
    actualizarTabla($("#e-fechaInicio").val(), $("#e-fechaFin").val());
  });
  $("#e-fechaFin").change(function() {
    actualizarTabla($("#e-fechaInicio").val(), $("#e-fechaFin").val());
  });

}
```

y mi tabla est así

```
$('#ejemplo').bootstrapTable({
    url: '<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/modulos/diegov/ejemplo/datos',
    columns:[
      {field: 'reStatus', cellStyle: cellStyle,filter:{type:"input"}},
      {field: 'ocTipoCompra',filter:{type:"input"}},
      {field: 'faClave', footerFormatter: totalItems,filter:{type:"input"}},
      {field: 'tiPesoNeto', footerFormatter: totalToneladas,filter:{type:"input"}},
      {field: 'inpo', footerFormatter: totalImporte,filter:{type:"input"}}
    ],

    pagination: true,
    showFooter: true,
    search: true,
    showExport:true,
    filter: true,
    method: 'post',
    showRefresh:true,
    showPaginationSwitch: true
  });
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar, gracias

Comment: falta que incluyas que tiene la funcion `obtenerTablaAjax` para poder ayudarte mejor, de igual forma: ¿tienes el codigo en un js aparte o esta dentro del codigo que pinta el php?, por que veo que tienes en las rutas el `<?= base_url(); ?>` esto debe primero interpretarlo el php

Comment: la función `obtenerTablaAjax` esta en un archivo `js` y esta asi 
`function obtenerTablaAjax(nombre,direccionAjax,opciones,dirImg){
    peticionDatos(
        direccionAjax,opciones,
        function(){ $('#'+nombre).replaceWith('<div id="cargando-Tabla"><img src="'+dirImg+'" /></div>') },
        function(datos){ $('#cargando-Tabla').replaceWith(datos); eventHandlersTabla(); }
    );
    $('#update-modal').modal("hide");
}` 
pero bueno mi problema es que me toma los parametros y me devielve el nuevo `JSON` con los datos filtrados pero no me pinta mi tabla con ellos

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a refrescar la tabla

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh');
```